# R: Extract list element but without index number in output

Tags: r

This seems to be a beginner question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. I know how to extract an element from a list using listname[[1]] but output will always include the index number like

```
[1] First element of the list
```

Same is true for using the name like listname$name or unlist(listname$name). All I want is

```
First element of the list
```

I could of course remove the index number using regex but I doubt that this is the way it should be :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the `[1]` appears is because all atomic types in R are vectors (of type character, numeric, etc), i.e. in your case a vector of length one.

If you want to see the output without the `[1]` the simples way is to `cat` the object:

```
> listname <- list("This is the first list element", 
                   "This is the second list element")
> cat(listname[[1]], "\n")
This is the first list element 
>
```

Comment: Validate the answer then ;)

Comment: This could be a problem when the output are ggplot objects.